# restore published agent version back to dialogflow

Tags: actions-on-google

My production agent/action version differs from my draft version in dialogflow. I want to restore my published production version back to dialogflow - I didn't export the zip at the time. Is there a way to get the production version back to current version in dialogflow?
thanks
Fiona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you have tackled this but you can probably try this (i haven't personally tried it myself). Go to the gear icon in dialogflow. Under general, turn on enable beta features and api. You will now see an environment tab on top. Click that and there is a link to view all versions. Then for the production version, there is 3 vertical dots link beside it.. click it and select Load to draft.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes! Thanks so much - you are Gold goldzulu!

Comment: No worries glad to be of service!